# Shunting-yard functions

Tags: java, algorithm, evaluation, infix-notation, shunting-yard

I am using the Shunting-Yard algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) in a Java program in order to create a calculator. I am almost done, but I still have to implement functions. I have ran into a problem: I want the calculator to automatically multiply variables like x and y when put together - Example: calculator converts xy to x*y. Also, I want the calculator to convert (x)(y) to (x)*(y) and x(y) to x*(y). I have done all of this using the following code:

```
infix = infix.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])", "$1*$2");
infix = infix.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z])\\(", "$1*(");
infix = infix.replaceAll("\\)\\(", ")*(");
infix = infix.replaceAll("\\)([a-zA-Z])", ")*$1");
```

(In my calculator, variable names are always single characters.)
This works great right now, but when I implement functions this will, of course, not work. It will turn "sin(1)" into "s*i*n*(1)". How can I make this code do the multiplication converting only for operators, and not for functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preprocessing the input to parse isn't a good way to implement what you want. The text replacement can't know what the parsing algorithm knows and you also lose the original input, which can be useful for printing helpful error messages.

Instead, you should decide on what to do according to the context. Keep the type of the previously parsed token wth a special type for the beginning of the input.

If the previous token was a value token – a number, a variable name or the closing brace of a subextression – and the current one is a value token, too, emit an extra multiplication operator.

The same logic can be used to decide whether a minus sign is a unary negation or a binary subtraction: It's a subtraction if the minus is found after a value token and a negation otherwise.

Your idea to convert `x(y)` to `x * (y)` will, of course, clash with function call syntax.

Answer (score 0):

We can break this down into two parts. There is one rule for bracketed expressions and another for multiplications.

Rather than the wikipedia article, which is a deliberately simplified for explanatory purposes, I would follow a more details example like [Parsing Expressions by Recursive Descent](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm) that deals with bracketed expressions.

This is the code I use for my parser which can work with implicit multiplication. I have multi-letter variable names and use a space to separate different variables so you can have "2 pi r".

```
protected void expression() throws ParseException  {
    prefixSuffix();
    Token t = it.peekNext();
    while(t!=null) {
        if(t.isBinary()) {
            pushOp(t);
            it.consume();
            prefixSuffix();
        }
        else if(t.isImplicitMulRhs()) {
            pushOp(implicitMul);
            prefixSuffix();
        }
        else
            break;
        t=it.peekNext();
    }
    while(!sentinel.equals(ops.peek())) {
        popOp();
    }
}
```

This require a few other functions.

I've used a separate tokenizing step which breaks the input into discrete tokens. The `Tokens` class has a number of methods, in particular `Token.isBinary()` test if the operator is a binary operator like +,=,*,/. Another method `Token.isImplicitMulRhs()` tests if the token can appear on the right hand side of an implicit multiplication, this will be true for numbers, variable names, and left brackets.

An `Iterator<Token>` is used for the input stream. `it.peekNext()` looks at the next token and `it.consume()` moves to the next token in the input.

`pushOp(Token)` pushes a token onto the operator stack and `popOp` removes one and . pushOp has the logic to handle the precedence of different operators. Popping operator if they have lower precedence

```
protected void pushOp(Token op)
{
    while(compareOps(ops.peek(),op))
        popOp();
    ops.push(op); 
}
```

Of particular note is `implicitMul` an artificial token with the same precedence as multiplication which is pushed onto the operator stack.

`prefixSuffix()` handles expressions which can be numbers and variables with optional prefix of suffix operators. This will recognise "2", "x", "-2", "x++" removing tokens from the input and added them to the output/operator stack as appropriate.

We can think of this routine in BNF as

```
<expression> ::= 
          <prefixSuffix> ( <binaryOp> <prefixSuffix> )* // normal binary ops x+y
          | <prefixSuffix> ( <prefixSuffix> )*  // implicit multiplication x y
```

Handling brackets is done in `prefixSuffix()`. If this detects a left bracket, it will then recursively call `expression()`. To detect the matching right bracket a special sentinel token is pushed onto the operator stack. When the right bracket is encountered in the input the main loop breaks, and all operators on the operator stack popped until the sentinel is encountered and control returned to `prefixSuffix()`. Code for this might be like

```
void prefixSuffix() {
    Token t = it.peekNext();
    if(t.equals('(')) {
         it.consume();  // advance the input
         operatorStack.push(sentinel);
         expression(); // parse until ')' encountered
         t = it.peekNext();
         if(t.equals(')')) {
             it.consume();  // advance the input
             return;
         } else throw Exception("Unmatched (");
     }
     // handle variable names, numbers etc 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach may be the use of tokens, in a similar way to how a parser work.

The first phase would be to convert the input text into a list of tokens, which are objects that represent both the type of entity found and its value.
For example you can have a variable token, with its value being the name of the variable ('x', 'y', etc.), a token for open or close parenthesis, etc.
Since, I assume, you know in advance the names of the functions that can be used by the calculator, you'll also have a function token, with its value being the function name.
So the output of the tokenizing phase differentiates between variables and functions.

Implementing this is not too hard, just always try to match function names first,
so "sin" will be recognized as a function and not as three variables.

Now the second phase can be to insert the missing multiplication operators. This will not be hard now, since you know you to just insert them between:

{VAR, RIGHT_PAREN} and {VAR, LEFT_PAREN, FUNCTION}

But never between FUNCTION and LEFT_PAREN.